# Delete Directories based on time modified

Tags: powershell, deployment, build

I am using Powershell scripts to deploy the codebase on our remote servers.

One Major part of the script copies the current release to the server. Now I just need to keep the last two releases on the remote server and delete all others.

**I Need to keep the latest two releases**

Eg:
In the remote server, I have

```
//server001/Application/
    Build_1_0_0_19
    Build_1_0_0_18
    Build_1_0_0_17
    Build_1_0_0_16
```

I need to clear Builds `_17` and `_16` while deploying `_19`.

We can sort out the directories according to the time modified and the last two will come on top. Rest all are not required.

Can this be done through Powershell Scripts ?

P.S. The builds are not always in sequential order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#requires -version 2
Get-ChildItem //server001/Application/|
    Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending|
    Select-Object -Skip 2|
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm
```

Just remove the `-Confirm` switch once you are sure that it does what you want.

Here is a v1 compatible method:

```
$dirs = @(Get-ChildItem //server001/Application/)

$dirs|
    Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending|
    Select-Object -Last ($dirs.Count - 2)|
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm
```

Comment: If you leave out the `-Recurse` switch on `Remove-Item`, you will be prompted for deleting any folders that contain other items.

Comment: Leaving out `CreationTime` from `Sort-Object` will sort by `Name`. The OP said the latest releases should be kept, and the builds are not in sequential order (which I assume means the build `names` are not in sequential order). `CreationTime` will find the latest build by time (otherwise `Build_1_0_0_100` will be seen as earlier than `Build_1_0_0_19`).

Comment: Getting the following Error buddy : `PS C:\> .\del_oldBuilds.ps1
Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Skip'.
At C:\del_oldBuilds.ps1:3 char:20
+ Select-Object -Skip  <<<< 2|`

Comment: Basically, the `-skip` handle is not working, the rest of the command works fine if I remove `-skip`, but that is a necessary requirement ... otherwise it deletes all the directories.

Comment: You must be using PowerShell v1.0; `-Skip` is new to v2.0. Are you permitted to upgrade to 2.0?

Comment: Sadly No :( ... btw, I got one more solution, but need a bit of help there too... in my ps script, I have the latest build label `Build_1_0_0_19` and previous build label `Build_1_0_0_18` caught in seprate variables. Not I can delete all the labels not matching these two .. any suggestions ??

Comment: @Arpit - Updated with a v1 method. Or using your variables you could use `Get-ChildItem //server001/Application/| where {('Build_1_0_0_19','Build_1_0_0_18') -notcontains $_.Name}| Remove-Item -Recurse`, replacing the names with your variables.